# Can redirection break onClick handler execution when preventDefault not used?

Tags: javascript

Let's assume I have the following code:

```
<a id="go" href="http//domain/url-to-another-page">Go there</a>

$('#go').on('click', event => {
  // can use preventDefault here

  // do some fency computations for ex.
  if (canTakeToken)  {
    localStorage.setItem('myToken, tokenValue - 1);
  }
});
```

Now the question is, will this handler be ALWAYS executed (when user clicks the element) or can it be broken (by the redirection) before being completed - assuming that we won't use `preventDefault`?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding too, yes, the event can be broken in many cases and not be completed, a common solution is like you have prepared - to call preventDefault() in the click event, and after other logic is complete - to extract target href and do the redirect via JavaScript.

Comment: While the handler remains on the `href` will be prevented, this is sure.

Comment: That's the answer, if you will place those as answers I'll accept it.

Comment: To undo the `event.preventDefault()` behavior you should use `$('#go').off('click')`